# Xamarin.Android doesn't create SQLite database

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm trying to create a database with Xamarin.Android but both on the emulator and on the tablet I do not receive an error but nothing is created, where am I wrong?

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // create variables for our onscreen widgets

        var btnCreate = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnCreateDB);

        // create DB path
        var docsFolder = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        var pathToDatabase = System.IO.Path.Combine(docsFolder, "db_sqlnet.db");

        // disable the single and list buttons until the database has been created
        btnSingle.Enabled = btnList.Enabled = false;

        // create events for buttons
        btnCreate.Click += delegate
        {
            var result = createDatabase(pathToDatabase);
            txtResult.Text = result + "\n";
            // if the database was created ok, then enable the list and single buttons
            if (result == "Database created")
                btnList.Enabled = btnSingle.Enabled = true;
        };


    private string createDatabase(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            var connection = new SQLiteConnection(path);
            connection.CreateTable< Entity.Person>();
            return "Database created";
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you I would use the folder `System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal` instead of `System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments`.

End when you open the connection with `new SQLiteConnection(path)` try to add `SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLiteOpenFlags.Create` as second parameter.

Comment: Thanks, now it creates the database but I don't find it on device !!!!!

Comment: What do you mean with "I don't find it on device"? How you know that it exists? What about the table?

Comment: There is no database file on device

Comment: Good, and why you wrote "now it creates the database" if it doesn't exist?

Comment: you're right I was unclear. In the example I copied, there is the opportunity to insert records into the database after creating it. Before, this part of the code did not work, not finding the database, now I have no exception so I assumed that the database was created. Sorry

Comment: "There is no database file on device"... so if think that the database was created why you wrote that there isn't? Aren't you able to find it? Have you tried to copy all the private folder using adb?

Comment: Look here: http://mpic.it/ispezionare-le-cartelle-private-di-unapp-android/ and if you solve please don't forget to mark the answer as solved

Comment: Thanks,it works, but how I can mark the answer as solved??

Comment: Great, glad that I've been useful. In theory there should be a grey check under the left panel you can use to mark the answer as useful. With the upper arrow you can give a positive vote (and the lower one a negative vote). If you click in the check button you are saying to other people reading your question that the answer you are marking is the correct one and it solves the problem.